# What can be an example of an element of such sets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm struggling with figuring out what $\mathbb R^{\mathbb Q}$ and $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R\times\mathbb Z}$ would look like let alone what might be the examples of elements of those sets. Could you please at least point out where should I be looking for an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $B^A$ can denote functions from $A $ to $B$

Comment: I went ahead and made those LaTeX changes for you. Please note how it was done by clicking the edit timestamp on your post.

Answer (score 2):

For two sets $X$ and $Y$, $X^Y$ is simply the set of all functions from $Y$ to $X$.

So, $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of all functions from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, etc.